# Querying for points within polygon in MySQL?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, mysql

I have polygon in this format

```
POLYGON(23.816364700000001 87.574939799999996 ,23.814872699999999 87.572279100000003 ,23.812595399999999 87.572279100000003 ,23.809925700000001 87.571678300000002 ,23.808276500000002 87.572794099999996 ,23.808040999999999 87.576227200000005 ,23.8096116 87.578802100000004 ,23.811417599999999 87.580432900000005 ,23.813537799999999 87.579402900000005 ,23.815814899999999 87.578029599999994 ,23.816443100000001 87.576999700000002)
```

I need to know if point 23.817578, 87.570492 is inside the POLYGON or not, using MySQL 5.6?